# Django - Hosting Platform query

Tags: django, postgresql, web-hosting

I have built a Django local web application which I want to host on some platform now. I am using Postgres SQL as database. Any recommendations of hosting platforms with cheaper or free plans? My website will be used by few users only (<50), so I don't need very powerful server/CPU etc.

Answer (score 0):

Vultr has plans starting at $2.50 which offers 1cpu and 512mb of ram.

- https://www.vultr.com/products/cloud-compute/

Other comparable clouds would be Digitalocean or Linode. As for a free option you may want to look into Heroku.